Yum update command showing some error
In a almalinux server with cpanel, when try to update yum with the command "yum update" throwing the following error. No commands are working. All commands outputs are the same. output are given below
Error Details:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/yum", line 58, in <module>
        main.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 201, in user_main
        errcode = main(args)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 67, in main
        return _main(base, args, cli_class, option_parser_class)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 102, in _main
        cli.configure(list(map(ucd, args)), option_parser())
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/cli/cli.py", line 830, in configure
        self.base.init_plugins(opts.disableplugin, opts.enableplugin, self)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 307, in init_plugins
        self._plugins._run_init(self, cli)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/plugin.py", line 154, in _run_init
        plugin = p_cls(base, cli)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf-plugins/spacewalk.py", line 79, in __init__
        self.activate_channels()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf-plugins/spacewalk.py", line 109, in activate_channels
        login_info = up2date_client.up2dateAuth.getLoginInfo(timeout=self.conf.timeout)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/up2date_client/up2dateAuth.py", line 231, in getLoginInfo
        login(timeout=timeout)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/up2date_client/up2dateAuth.py", line 198, in login
        li = server.up2date.login(systemId, socket.getfqdn())
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/up2date_client/rhnserver.py", line 67, in __call__
        return rpcServer.doCall(method, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/up2date_client/rpcServer.py", line 222, in doCall
        ret = method(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1112, in __call__
        return self.__send(self.__name, args)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/up2date_client/rpcServer.py", line 48, in _request1
        ret = self._request(methodname, params)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rhn/rpclib.py", line 394, in _request
        self._handler, request, verbose=self._verbose)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rhn/transports.py", line 194, in request
        return self._process_response(fd, connection)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rhn/transports.py", line 222, in _process_response
        return self.parse_response(fd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rhn/transports.py", line 245, in parse_response
        p.close()
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 448, in close
        parser.Parse(b"", True) # end of data
    xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: syntax error: line 1, column 0


Looks like its connecting to some spacewalk host. Disable the spacewalk plugin potentially and see if it works then. Also suggests very strongly whatever source you're using for updates (spacewalk) is more broke than your client.

This is a spacewalk connectivity/handshaking/something error. As I'm sure you know, spacewalk is fairly deprecated (I should know, I run one for a legacy product myself), but cpanel can be a real pain to set up from scratch so I understand trying to get the most out of what you have set up.
I would make sure you can log into the spacew2alk server on its webui to ensure it looks normal (or if someone else is the one with access, request them to check it out with the same idea).
Now, if spacewalk is totally down are you want to update things without spacewalk, you can run yum repolist and if you can identify the repos that are using spacewalk, you can use yum --disablerepo=name_of_spacewalk_repo for each one and either retry what is left or do the yum --enablerepo=repo you want.
You can even create a cdrom repo if you have an ISO with the updates you need.
I have a machine where I am trying to go around spacewalk for some newer updates and ?I mounted the iso at /mnt/cdrom. Here is what I have as cdrom.repo:
    [cdrom]
name=Local ISO Repo
baseurl=file:///mnt/cdrom
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1

I hope that helps.
